# 1 Link opens 1 Iframe and scrolls to the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

How can I make it so a link will not only open a new page in an iframe, but also redirect the webpage to the top of the screen? if possible using just html/css code.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with just HTML or CSS.  If you are wanting to open an iframe on the same page as the link that you clicked, you would have to create a script that dynamically fills the scr attribute of the iframe.

If you are trying to create a link that opens a new page that has an iframe, then you set the target attribute of the  tag to _blank like so:

```
<a href="" target="_blank">
```

iframes will navigate to a page specified by their src attribute.  To get an iframe to go to a specific point in the page without scripting, there would have to be an element on the page the iframe is going to that has an id.  You would then specify this id in the address of you iframe's src attribute like so:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/#idyouaretargeting"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you know any other possibilities to make this happen with maybe java? Grant it i do not know alot about java at all.